# Error in running .py with tensorflow and keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have `Keras 2.4.3`  and `TF 2.3.0` installed. I am using GPU for training my model.
The training code is in `ipynb` format and `py` format. When  I use `Jupyter lab` to run the code in `ipynb` format, it works. But when I use the terminal to run the same code in `.py` format, it pops out the following error:

> line 146, in **del** TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
> Exception ignored in: <function
> _CheckpointRestoreCoordinatorDeleter.**del** at 0x7fb593342160> Traceback (most recent call last):

There is no error when I run the code in `ipynb` format.
The error only pops up when I use exactly the same code in `py` format and run it from the terminal.

Comment: can you post a reproducible example ? also you can use [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) to set a breakpoint just before line 146.

Comment: Change the way of save and restore Checkpoint manager may be helpful. `manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(
    checkpoint, directory="/tmp/model", max_to_keep=5)`, use the absolute path. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not shared a code example, so we can only guess.
The error indicates that the problem is related to restoring a checkpoint.

This can be alleviated using `expect_partial()`: For example:

```
`model.load_weights(path).expect_partial()`
```

or

```
`checkpoint.restore(path).expect_partial()`
```

See `tensorflow/python/training/tracking/util.py`.